# Does someone know how to connect and read from OBD-II (ELM 327) in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, obd-ii

I'm new to this and I'm finding really hard to understand how to receive data from the OBD-II, and what I find about it it's only for Android, java, but I'm looking for C#, Xamarin.Forms.

My OBD-II is currently connected to my car, and what I want to do is getting the speed, temperature, etc. from it through a Xamarin app.

If someone could help me, please!

Comment: I would first attempt to do this as a Proof-of-concept app as a console app. How is the adapter connected to the computer?

Comment: These devices are usually simple Serial over Bluetooth devices. So you will need to create a socket over bluetooth and send and respond to the commands it sends.

Comment: @phuzi Atm the adapter is connected to my car! I already edited the post so people could understand, sorry about that. I'm gonna need to connect the phone to the adapter, and then get the information like speed, and more.

Comment: Of course it will need to be connected to the car! I was asking how it will be connected to the computer. From your comment, I'll assume that it's a simple serial over Bluetooth device and therefore you will be connecting to it over Bluetooth.

Comment: @phuzi Yes, through Bluetooth! I already installed an app to see how it worked called Car Scanner, and it's something like it that I'd like to do, but just get a really specific info.

Comment: Here is a list of AT commands it supports over serial: https://www.elmelectronics.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/AT_Command_Table.pdf